# Association of else block with if block in C

Tags: c, if-statement

I have a code snippet as shown below. Can someone please explain me why the else block is getting associated with the nested if block? The output of the following snippet is `1`. I executed the code but cannot understand why the blocks are getting associated in the following order.

UPDATE: This is a question I found in a company's previous year interview questions. I always use brackets around my `if` and `else` blocks. I now understand why the entire block is not getting executed.

Thank You everyone for your responses :)

```
int x=1, y=1;
if (y<0)
    if (y>0) x=3;
    else x=5;
printf("%d", x);
```

Comment: C or C++? Please try and be specific as these languages can differ in substantial ways despite having a lot of similarity. Just specify whichever you're most interested in.

Comment: PSA: This is why you should *always* use braces (`{ ... }`) on your `if` statements.

Comment: Because that's how C++ works?

Comment: Because that the language syntax rules. If in doubt - use brackets

Comment: ALWAYS use braces to fence your if/else statements. Unless you write Python of course.

Comment: [From C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.4.1p3): *An else is associated with the lexically nearest preceding if that is allowed by the syntax.*

Comment: Just use clang format and everything will be clear. There is also clang-tidy which can automatically add braces to avoid confusion. Many IDEs have this tools build in/preinstalled.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if

Comment: I started using the [Allman Indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Allman_style) decades ago when I was a n00b (Mind you, I'm not sure n00b was a thing back then) to help me keep the structure clear in my head. I never stopped using it. It's just too helpful. It makes all manner of bugs obvious or impossible.

Comment: It's a sadly low bar, but at least the question wasn't immediately deleted.

Comment: An answer to this question can be found in any introductory C++ book. At least, this question shows zero research effort. If this is a question about grammar and parsing (I guess it's not), this should be explicitly stated in the question body.

Comment: @Evg: Re “An answer to this question can be found in any introductory C++ book”: (a) No, it cannot. The question is not **which** `if` an `else` is associated with, which is answered in an introductory C++ book, the question is **why** an `else` is associated with the nearer `if`. I just checked an introductory C++ book, and it did not answer that. (b) That is not a reason for voting to close or voting down.

Comment: @tadman The language is C. I used C/C++ because I thought the rules would be same as the languages are similar.

Comment: C and C++ have commonality, but it's important to specify which one you're using as there are often *significant* differences, even on basic stuff like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formal C and C++ grammars do not specify how an `else` is associated. The choice is specified by a rule outside the grammar. C 2018 6.8.4.1 3 says:

> An `else` is associated with the lexically nearest preceding `if` that is allowed by the syntax.

C++ 2020 (draft N4849) 8.5.1 [stmt.if] 1 says:

> … In the second form of `if` statement (the one including `else`), if the first substatement is also an `if` statement then that inner `if` statement shall contain an `else` part. [In other words, an `else` has to be associated with the inner `if` before the outer `if` can have an `else`.]

To see the grammar does not specify how an `else` is associated, we can examine the formal grammar in C 2018 6.8.4:

> *selection-statement*:
>     `if` `(` *expression* `)` *statement*
>     `if` `(` *expression* `)` *statement* `else` *statement*
>     `switch` `(` *expression* `)` *statement*

With this grammar, `if(y<0) if(y>0) x=3; else x=5;` may be parsed as `if(y>0) x=3; else x=5;` being one *statement* that is “`if` `(` *expression* `)` *statement* `else` *statement*”, or it may be parsed with `if(y>0) x=3;` being one *statement* that is `if` `(` *expression* `)` *statement*. In the former case, the parent `if(y>0)` would have the `if` form without an `else`. In the latter case, the parent `if(y>0)` would have the `if … else` form.

Answer (score 6):

With the proper indentation, it becomes clearer:

```cpp
    int x = 1, y = 1;

    if (y < 0)         // false, so it jumps directly here
        if (y > 0)     //                                |
            x = 3;     //                                |
        else           //                                |
            x = 5;     //                                |
    printf("%d", x);   // <------------------------------+
```

Adding braces makes it even clearer. The below has exactly the same meaning as your original code:

```cpp
    int x = 1, y = 1;

    if (y < 0) {
        if (y > 0) {
            x = 3;
        } else {
            x = 5;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", x);
```

That is, `if(condition) <statement> else <statement>`. The `<statement>` can be either a single statement or a `{`block`}` statement. Without braces, only the next single statement will be conditionally executed.

Answer (score 3):

The if statements is defined the following way (for simplicity I am using the C grammar)

```
selection-statement:
    if ( expression ) statement
    if ( expression ) statement else statement
```

As you can see, the `else` part can not exist as a separate statement without the `if` part.

So, according to the definition, this `if` statement:

```c
if(y<0) ...
```

can be rewritten like:

```c
if(y<0) statement;
```

The *statement* can be any statement, including another `if` statement:

```c
if(y<0) if(y>0) x=3; else x=5;
```

That is, the `else` part belongs to the closest `if` part.

Otherwise, you could write:

```c
if(y<0) 
{ 
    if(y>0) x=3; 
}
else x=5;
```

In this case, the *statement* is the compound statement with the enclosed `if` statement without the `else` part.

```c
{ 
    if(y>0) x=3; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As if you are asking for logical explanation why things they are let's look into this code:

```
if( condition1 ) 
    if( condition2 ) x = 1;
    else x = 2;
else x = 3;
```

if it would work as you suggested or expected then commenting out line `else x = 3;` would make statement `else x = 2;` magically jump from `if( condition2 )` to `if( condition1 )` and where `else x = 2` belongs to would depend of existence of `else x = 3;` which is a very bad practice. But if you are in doubt use `{}` to express what you need clearly and unambiguous way:

```
if( condition1 ) { 
    if( condition2 ) x = 1;
}
else x = 2;
```

Comment: The same problem applies currently though. The way it actually works, if I comment out `else x = 2;` then `else x=3;` suddenly jumps. Either way one depends on the other.

Answer (score 2):

The rules of associativity for `if..else` in C and C++ (and several other languages) are designed to support `if..else if` chains without excessive (visual) nesting:

```c
if(a) handle_a();
else if(b) handle_b();
else if(c) handle_c();
else handle_other();
```

which is actually:

```c
if(a) {
    handle_a();
} else {
    if(b) {
        handle_b();
    } else {
        if(c) {
            handle_c();
        } else {
            handle_other();
        }
    }
}
```

It's not too hard to design a syntax in which the less-indented version works properly, simply by special casing `else if` (as many other languages do, generally by having a special `elseif` keyword), but C accomplishes this behavior more elegantly, by introducing a rule that an `else` becomes the `else` for the closest preceding `if`. That leads to a specific behavior of `if(a); if (b); else c();` which isn't particularly useful or obvious, but it keeps the rules simple(r).

Comment: Some programmers would still insist on formatting `else` `if` chains with an indented line break between the `else` and the `if` like your bracketed example, even without the brackets. Of course, that can soon lead to a deeply nested, unreadable mess. So most C programmers like to treat `else if` as a single entity like `elseif` (or `elif` or whatever) for sanity's sake. Readability wins over strictly logical indentation in this case!